# "uk-resident" tag - merge it with "residency" or "uk-citizens" tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tagging, tag-synonyms

I just discovered we have a [uk-resident](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-resident) tag.

It at least needs to me **made plural**, but ...

But is that enough? Should it be merged with either of these more well known and used tags:

- [uk-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-citizens) - residency is not the same as citizenship but so far we've got along without a set of citizenship tags. Is it time to start creating them as needed now? Or would it be better to explicitly declare the existing citizenship tags to also cover residency?
- [residency](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/residency) - this isn't as established but it would seem to cover all questions where a person's residency status might affect what they're allowed to de beyond their citizenship. Is this a better tag than allowing a `-residents` tag in addition to the `-citizens` tags? Would we need both?

Comment: I like the initiative to get very precise tags. 'Residency' is very context dependent. Students have residency for NHS purposes, but they are not 'normally resident'.  Spouses have normal residency, but not the 'residency' that enables resident tuition.  And there's a *big* distinction between 'normally resident' and 'permanent residence' (ILR). People often use 'resident' without disclosing the context and it's very confusing when they do that.There's also a 'residence' permit (EEA) and 'permanent residence' derived from EEA regs, and not through ILR rules. A den of snakes. Please be careful.

Comment: @pnuts: There's some writing in old blog posts or SE.meta about not combining tags in such ways and that they should each be able to stand on their own.

Comment: @pnuts: "visas" and "uk" are both standalone. Many new users just use one or the other. Plus we have a growing set of tags for special visas. We just don't have COUNTRY-visa tags, which I think is good. The more specific ones such as "b1 b2 visas" add more value, I think.

Comment: @pnuts: If "residency" were standalone it would seem to be for questions about residency, which is of topic here. Just as we have tags for 'USA citizens' etc but questions "abuout" citizenship are off topic. We don't support questions about residency or citizenship but we do support questions pertaining to citizens and residents of specific places. The more I spell this out the more I think we should just burninate the residency tag and create the specific xyz-residents tags as we need them.

Comment: I disagree with randomly making combinations of tag pairs. We could do that with almost any tag or pair such as usa-passports, uk-air-travel, train-tickets, french-airports, etc. It seems to be some just kind of pop out and make sense to split out whereas others would just be some kind of matching game of no value.

Answer (score 6):

I would choose to **not** merge [uk-resident](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-resident) with [uk-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-citizens). As rightly pointed out by [Gayot Flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow):

> I like the initiative to get very precise tags. 'Residency' is very
>   context dependent. Students have residency for NHS purposes, but they
>   are not 'normally resident'. Spouses have normal residency, but not
>   the 'residency' that enables resident tuition. And there's a big
>   distinction between 'normally resident' and 'permanent residence'
>   (ILR). People often use 'resident' without disclosing the context and
>   it's very confusing when they do that.There's also a 'residence'
>   permit (EEA) and 'permanent residence' derived from EEA regs, and not
>   through ILR rules. A den of snakes. Please be careful.

As a UK resident-but-not-citizen, I know in a lot of travel situations it makes a huge difference in what rules apply. Although, as Gayot Flow also points out, there's different interpretations of how those rules apply.

I'd vote to keep as-is, and give a quick explainer of the different kinds of residency in the tag wiki.

We should definitely make it a plural though.

Comment: When you say "as is", you think we should keep the "residency" tag **and** also gradually accrue "xx-residents" tags like the UK? (Personally I think we're getting big enough that accruing the tags as they are needed would be good, with good tag wikis. I can't think of a good use for the nonspecific "residency" tag though.)